# Construct coordinates in nested loop

Tags: python, loops

I want to construct the following coordinates in a loop:

```
 (65, 570)
 (865, 570)
 (65, 1090)
 (865, 1090)
 (65, 1610)
 (865, 1610)
```

Here's my code:

```
pos_y = 570
pos_x = 65
for fila in range(len(pics)):
    pos_x = 65
    for columna in range(len(pics)-1):
        print(pos_x, pos_y)
        pos_y = 570
        pos_x = pos_x + 800
```

The problem is that my loop, Doesn't update the value of pos_y. What I im doing wrong?. The output:

```
65 570
865 570
65 570
865 570
65 570
865 570
```

Comment: You are setting the value of `pos_y` to **570** in your second for loop and not updating it. You can update it by doing `pos_y += 570` which is the same as `pos_y = pos_y + 570`

Comment: `pos_y = pos_y + 570
        pos_x = pos_x + 800`

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib Nope, if i update the value in the second loop, I will not have the expected output. Try it

Comment: Then it is a mixture of more mathematical computation that is involved. Why are we expecting those specific co-ordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pos_y = 570
for fila in range(len(pics)):
    pos_x = 65
    for columna in range(len(pics)-1):
        print(pos_x, pos_y)
        pos_x += 800
    pos_y += 520
```